# Show that $\lim\limits_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^T |\varphi(t)|^2 dt = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}}(\mu (\{x\}))^2$

Tags: probability-theory

I want to show that $\lim\limits_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^T |\varphi(t)|^2 dt = \mathbb{P}(X-Y=0) =\sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}}(\mu (\{x\}))^2$ for X, Y random variables, that are i.i.d., and $\varphi(t)$ is the characteristic function of X and Y and $\mu$ is the distribution.

I have already shown the second equality but I really don't know how to show the first one.
My idea was to use the inversion theorem, but I don't know what to do with the $\frac{1}{2T}$...

Do you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$\text{Si}(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin x}x,& x\ne 0,\\1,& x=0.\end{cases}$$
then 
$$ |\text{Si}(x)|\le 1, \qquad \lim_{|T|\to\infty}\text{Si}(xT)=1_{\{0\}}(x),\qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.\tag{1}$$
Clearly,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[e^{i(X-Y)t}]&=\mathsf{E}[e^{iXt}]\mathsf{E}[e^{-iYt}]=|\phi(t)|^2. \\
\frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T |\phi(t)|^2\,dt&=\frac1{2T}\mathsf{E}\Bigl[\int_{-T}^Te^{i(X-Y)t}\,dt\Bigr]=\mathsf{E}[\text{Si}((X-Y)T)]
\end{align}
Now using (1) and Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, we find that
\begin{align} \lim_{T\to\infty} \frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T |\phi(t)|^2\,dt &=\lim_{T\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[\text{Si}((X-Y)T)]
=\mathsf{E}[\lim_{T\to\infty}\text{Si}((X-Y)T)] \\
&=\mathsf{E}[1_{\{X=Y\}}]=\mathsf{P}(X=Y).
\end{align}